# How to get supplier id when it has just been added in the db?

Tags: php, content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When I add a supplier in the admin panel (and click the save button) I want to retrieve its ID in the method **postProcess()** in the controller

**prestashop/controllers/admin/AdminSuppliersController.php**

in such a way that I can associate to this supplier other custom info in custom tables in the DB. I can't find in code the part when it stores the supplier to the db (I find only the part when it inserts the address relative to the supplier in ps_address table).

Here the default **postProcess()** method:

```
public function postProcess()
{
    // checks access
    if (Tools::isSubmit('submitAdd'.$this->table) && !($this->tabAccess['add'] === '1')) {
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You do not have permission to add suppliers.');
        return parent::postProcess();
    }

    if (Tools::isSubmit('submitAdd'.$this->table)) {
        if (Tools::isSubmit('id_supplier') && !($obj = $this->loadObject(true))) {
            return;
        }

        // updates/creates address if it does not exist
        if (Tools::isSubmit('id_address') && (int)Tools::getValue('id_address') > 0) {
            $address = new Address((int)Tools::getValue('id_address'));
        } // updates address
        else {
            $address = new Address();
        } // creates address

        $address->alias = Tools::getValue('name', null);
        $address->lastname = 'supplier'; // skip problem with numeric characters in supplier name
        $address->firstname = 'supplier'; // skip problem with numeric characters in supplier name
        $address->address1 = Tools::getValue('address', null);
        $address->address2 = Tools::getValue('address2', null);
        $address->postcode = Tools::getValue('postcode', null);
        $address->phone = Tools::getValue('phone', null);
        $address->phone_mobile = Tools::getValue('phone_mobile', null);
        $address->id_country = Tools::getValue('id_country', null);
        $address->id_state = Tools::getValue('id_state', null);
        $address->city = Tools::getValue('city', null);

        $validation = $address->validateController();

        // checks address validity
        if (count($validation) > 0) {
            foreach ($validation as $item) {
                $this->errors[] = $item;
            }
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The address is not correct. Please make sure all of the required fields are completed.');
        } else {
            if (Tools::isSubmit('id_address') && Tools::getValue('id_address') > 0) {
                $address->update();
            } else {
                $address->save();
                // here I want to get the ID of the inserted supplier
                $_POST['id_address'] = $address->id;
            }
        }
        return parent::postProcess();
    } elseif (Tools::isSubmit('delete'.$this->table)) {
        if (!($obj = $this->loadObject(true))) {
            return;
        } elseif (SupplyOrder::supplierHasPendingOrders($obj->id)) {
            $this->errors[] = $this->l('It is not possible to delete a supplier if there are pending supplier orders.');
        } else {
            //delete all product_supplier linked to this supplier
            Db::getInstance()->execute('DELETE FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_supplier` WHERE `id_supplier`='.(int)$obj->id);

            $id_address = Address::getAddressIdBySupplierId($obj->id);
            $address = new Address($id_address);
            if (Validate::isLoadedObject($address)) {
                $address->deleted = 1;
                $address->save();
            }
            return parent::postProcess();
        }
    } else {
        return parent::postProcess();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the hook `actionObjectSupplierAddAfter` to get the supplier object right after it was added to database using in your module something like:

```
public function hookActionObjectSupplierAddAfter($params) {
    $supplier = $params['object'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but could you be more specific? I'm a noob here... where I have to insert (and then call) this function?

Comment: That function would go into a custom module you create, find out more here http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module . To make sure the function will be called, register the module on the hook in the `install()` function using `$this->registerHook('actionObjectSupplierAddAfter')`

Comment: This is very useful but I can't fetch the Object Id in this hook... any other idea?